# Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage Splitting a PDF into Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I was previously using CarrierWave and ImageMagick to split PDFs into images using something like this:

```
def pdf_to_imgs
  manipulate! do |img, index|
    image.format = 'png'
    image.write("path/to/images/image-#{index}.png")
  end
end
```

With Rails 5.2, ActiveStorage seems to be the way to go for uploading, so I am trying to migrate everything.

I have the following and it technically works:

```
def pdf_to_imgs
  path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(self.pdf)
  page_count = MiniMagick::Image.open(path).pages.count
  pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(path).convert("jpg")
  images = page_count.times.map do |page_number|
    pipeline.loader(page: page_number).call
  end
  images.each_with_index do |slide, i|
    self.images.attach(io: File.open(pdf), filename: "pdf-#{i}.jpg", content_type: "image/jpg")
  end
end
```

But, I was curious if this is the best way to go about it, or if there was a better way? For example, I was hoping to pass in an array to the attach method, but was getting an error. The above process also seems to take quite a long time to execute (albeit with large PDF files).

And, the console hangs on "Performed ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob", but I assume that's just because it's an async job.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? Im interested in displaying preview images for pdf files. But active storage only comes out of the box with functionality to display the first page of the pdf as a preview. Hopefully this will allow me to display previews of all pages. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Verty00 Sorry for the late reply! I ended up using a refactored version of the above code and then put it into a DelayedJob with a service object.

Comment: Awesome. If you have time it would be awesome if you added it to your question as an edit. I’d love to see

Comment: @Verty00 could you post your refactored solution as an answer to this question? That'd be very helpful!

Comment: @JackCollins I think its OP who has the refactored code. Id love to see it too.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake. @Justin do you have the updated code?

Comment: one security note, when using this approach you may get `identify-im6.q16: not authorized ` error which relates to PostScript security issue described in https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/pdf-not-authorized.html .